# What's the best working format for video making?

Tags: file-formats

Good day.
I'm trying learning Premiere, but at the moment i'm using Corel Video Studio to make video footage.

I noticed cpu-spiking and freezing editing my video (with both programs): in particular i'm using source video x264 econded with Handbrake.

My cpu is a Ryzen 5 1600 six cores with 8gb ram.

I'm working on a mechanical HDD.

So my question is: what's the best and low impact video format for working/editing ?

Comment: Welcome! "Best" is rather subjective, especially without more details. What resolution is your source material? Are you working on professional projects or something personal? How are your acquiring your source material? What qualities are important to you besides performance? (For example, future proofing, small file size, delivery to broadcasters/streamers.)

Answer (score 1):

The best format is using a temporal file of lower resolution.

Make a copy of your source material at half size, which will become 1/4 of the weight, then use some format that is compatible with your program and use it for the editing process, when it is ready, relink the videos to the original ones for the final render and done. Make some tests and see if the keyframes are working fine for small clips.

If you only want to change the source material to another format you are degrading your video.

Answer (score 0):

I use Cinegy Daniel2 codec for editing in Premiere Pro.
This codec take more space on disk, but work veeeeery fast compare to H264.
Also it work more fast for me compare to ProRes.

Cinegy Daniel2 can be replaced with DNxHD MXF OP1a or MXF OP1a.
Try these codecs. In Premiere it works very good.

Comment: Welcome! Just a bit of clarification. [MXF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_Exchange_Format) OP1a (and the other [operational patterns](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ugyk3Cg23ywC&lpg=PA233&ots=H4VFycH1aS&pg=PA233#v=onepage&q&f=false)) are containers, not codecs. MXF can be a great choice for a mezzanine format in a professional setting, but may not be right for casual use.

Comment: Thanks for corrections @MichaelLiebman .
I use Cinegy Daniel2 in generally for 4K videos. Or 4K multicam editing. Or when I want more smooth workflow in Premiere :)
I agreed with you that "best" is rather subjective, but from context I've understood that stighy want to improve him workflow in his editing program.
When I say improve I mean more smooth process without brakes.